# Find the area enclosed by the curve

Tags: calculus, integration

How can i find the area enclosed by the curves: $x=2+4\sin(\beta)$ and $y=3-2\cos(\beta)$.

I did try to find the values of $\beta$:
as: $\beta=\arcsin((x/4)-(1/2))$, 
$\beta=\arccos((y/2)-(3/2))$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint. For $\beta\in [0,2\pi]$, $x(\beta)=2+4\sin(\beta)$ and $y(\beta)=3-2\cos(\beta)$ are the parametric equations of an [ellipse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Parametric_representation) centred at $(2,3)$ with semiaxes $4$ and $2$.

We can find the [area enclosed by this closed curve $C$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area#Area_in_calculus) by evaluating the integral
$$\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{C} -y\,dx+x\,dy=
\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{2\pi} (-yx'+xy')d\beta.
$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: please continue the answer :)

Comment: @Bez Sof Try to evaluate the integral. The final answer should be $8\pi$ (see also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Area)

Comment: thanks a lot :)

Comment: @Bez Sof You are welcome! BTW, if you are new here, take a tour: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: can you please show a graph.thanks

Comment: @Bez Sof https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametric+plot+(2%2B4sin+t,+3-2cos(t))